# Pros and Cons of Listeners as WeakReferences

Tags: java, design-patterns, observer-pattern, weak-references

What are the pros and cons of keeping listeners as WeakReferences?

The big 'Pro' of course is that:

Adding a listener as a WeakReference means the listener doesn't need to bother 'removing' itself.

For those worried about the listener having the only reference to the object, why can't there be 2 methods, addListener() and addWeakRefListener()?

Those who don't care about removal can use the latter.

Comment: @user: http://weblogs.java.net/blog/enicholas/archive/2006/05/understanding_w.html

Comment: what would two methods buy you, except cluttering the api? While it is (still?) good style to remove all listeners that were added if possible, usually it doesn't hurt not doing so: garbage collection takes care except in in very rare cases. If you hit a memory leakage produced by a not-released listener, carefully analyse the situation and do something analoguous to what AbstractButton does with its Action's propertyChangeListener

Comment: if you have a weak referenced listener, you wont need to 'carefully analyse the situation' ;)

Comment: I do use weak listeners but not as part of the interface, only internally, that enforces keeping an external reference to the listener AND deregistering (anon. classes may not have the said reference). Otherwise there is a reference kept that just leaks. It's important to remember that any addXXXListener must be followed by removeXXXListener to ensure normal lifecycle. Deregistering is not an option (unless both objects have the same life cycle scope). The pattern is both useful w/ swing alikes and in esp. for server development.

Comment: @pdeva,  
*if you have a weak referenced listener, you wont need to 'carefully analyse the situation' ;)* that's so wrong, so wrong, if you have a weak listener, the one registered for the event will receive nothing since there will be no extra references left and the listener will be GC'd

Comment: Lots of answers here from people who can't think of why a WeakReference would make any sense, so I thought I'd at least add a reference to what I think is the prototypical problem it solves: the [lapsed listener problem](http://wikipedia.org/wiki/Lapsed_listener_problem).

Answer (score 78):

First of all, using WeakReference in listeners lists will give your object different **semantic**, then using hard references. In hard-reference case addListener(...) means "notify supplied object about specific event(s) **until I stop it explicitly** with removeListener(..)", in weak-reference case it means "notify supplied object about specific event(s) **until this object will not be used by anybody else** (or explicitly stop with removeListener)". Notice, it is perfectly legal in many situations to have object, listening for some events, and having no other references keeping it from GC. Logger can be an example.

As you can see, using WeakReference not just solve one problem ("I should keep in mind to not forget to remove added listener somewhere"), but also rise another -- "I should keep in mind that my listener can stop listen at any moment when there is no reference to it anymore". You not solve problem, you just trade one problem for another. Look, **in any way** you've forced to clearly define, design and trace livespan of you listener -- one way or another.

So, personally, I agree with mention what use WeakReference in listeners lists is more like a hack than a solution. It's pattern worth to know about, sometimes it can help you -- to make legacy code work well, for example. But it is not pattern of choice :)

P.S. Also it should be noted what WeakReference introduce additional level of indirection, which, in some cases with extremely high event rates, can reduce performance.

Comment: Another problem of using the WeakReference - "I should keep in mind that any state changes caused by my Listener may still happen after it has fallen out of scope". Because of this a WeakReference Listener will need to be designed with the knowledge that its existence is non-deterministic.

Comment: Yes, you definitely right. But it seems from my expirience what where is rather many cases when it is not an issue -- what is why the question is arise :) And you can see examples of using WeakReference for listeners even in jdk code, as far as I recall :)

Comment: Do you have any references for the WeakReference being used as a listener in the jdk? I'd be interested to see where it is used.

Comment: @Bringer128 Well, it seems I was wrong. I've seen many uses of WR-based listeners **around** swing, but looking sources I can't find any examples **inside**. JDK uses more interesting technic -- listeners list itself uses ordinary reference, but concrete listener serves as adapter, holding only WeakRef to actual object reciving events -- and it deregister itself as target GC-ed. Interesting :)

Comment: Can't say about JDK, but Android SDK uses one - SharedPreference is one of the examples. It uses WaekHashMap to store registered listeners.
http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.2_r1/android/app/SharedPreferencesImpl.java#167

May be naming methods which exploits weakrefs like `addWeakListener(listener)` may be a good practice as user of this class will have an idea what is going on inside to avoid missing notifies

Comment: Not using weak referenced callbacks leads to the world where each object has to have "destructor". And this defeats whole point of having GC.

Answer (score 35):

This is not a complete answer, but the very strength you cite can also be its principal weakness.  Consider what would happen if action listeners were implemented weakly:

```
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    // blah
});
```

That action listener is going to get garbage collected at any moment!  It's not uncommon that the only reference to an anonymous class is the event to which you are adding it.

Comment: why cant there be 2 methods, addListener() and addWeakRefListener()? those who dont care about removal can use the latter

Comment: @pdeva, yes, that would work.  It's a bit dangerous though that people have to remember which method to call.  I don't think this pattern is necessarily something you should **always** avoid, but it better have a good reason -- and IMO that reason cannot simply be "prevent mistakes by forgetful programmers."

Comment: "prevent mistakes by forgetful programmers." Isnt that why GC was invented? :) Also it keeps your code simpler since you dont have to remember to remove the listener when disposing an object.

Comment: @pdeva, I do not mean it's a bad principle to uphold.  But I believe the medicine is at least as bad as the symptom -- if they forget to use the medicine properly (add the listener using the wrong method) they'll be in even worse shape than the normal solution.

Answer (score 12):

I have seen tons of code where listeners were not unregistered properly. This means they were still called unnecessarily to perform unnecessary tasks.

If only one class is relying on a listener, then it is easy to clean, but what happens when 25 classes rely on it? It becomes much trickier to unregister them properly. The fact is, your code can start with one object referencing your listener and end up in a future version with 25 objects referencing that same listener.

Not using `WeakReference` is equivalent to taking a big risk of consuming unnecessary memory and CPU. It is more complicated, trickier and requires more work with hard references in the complex code.

`WeakReferences` are full of pros, because they are cleaned up automatically. The only con is that you must not forget to keep a hard reference elsewhere in your code. Typically, that would in objects relying on this listener.

I hate code creating anonymous class instances of listeners (as mentioned by Kirk Woll), because once registered, you can't unregister these listeners anymore. You don't have a reference to them. It is really bad coding IMHO.

You can also `null` a reference to a listener when you don't need it anymore. You don't need to worry about it anymore.

Comment: You can get the array of listeners for a given component.  Anonymous classes can extend a specialization.  Give that specialized listener class a uid property and you are all set for removing anon listeners selectively.

Comment: The anonymous listener that you dislike should only be registered if it should never be unregistered. If you save it to a variable/field/collection for later de-registration then would you consider that acceptable?

Comment: While I agree with you that anonymous listeners are a double-edged sword, the same is true for me for using weak references: To null a reference to the listener to remove it, is somewhat anti-semantic. You'd need to comment this line, that this means that the listener is unregistered any time in the future. In my opinion, the programmer is responsible for registering listeners, so he's responsible to remove them too.

Comment: @maenu I totally agree that it is the programmer's responsibility to register and unregister listeners. No discussion about that. What I am trying to argue is that it is much simpler and less risky to use weak references...

Comment: Here's another con of relying on weak references-- let's say I have 1000 listeners (views) onto an evolving simulation (model) and the views can come and go very dynamically.  And let's say some user action (e.g. interactive window resize) can cause all the views to go away and be recreated, say 100 times.  I then have 100,000 lapsed listeners... if the observerd holds them as WRs, they will *eventually* be cleaned up by GC... but until that time, they will all be listening and doing possibly expensive work, causing significant (temporary) slowdown.

Answer (score 6):

There are really no pros. A weakrefrence is usually used for "optional" data, such as a cache where you don't want to prevent garbage collection. You don't want your listener garbage collected, you want it to keep listening.

**Update:**

Ok, I think I might have figured out what you are getting at. If you are adding short-lived listeners to long-lived objects there may be benefit in using a weakReference. So for example, if you were adding PropertyChangeListeners to your domain objects to update the state of the GUI that is constantly being recreated, the domain objects are going to hold on to the GUIs, which could build up. Think of a big popup dialog that is constantly being recreated, with a listener reference back to an Employee object via a PropertyChangeListener. Correct me if I'm wrong, but I don't think the whole PropertyChangeListener pattern is very popular anymore.

On the other hand, if you are talking about listeners between GUI elements or having domain objects listening to GUI elements, you won't be buying anything, since when the GUI goes away, so will the listeners.

Here are a couple interesting reads:

http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t19468.html

[How to resolve swing listener memory leaks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1878127/how-to-resolve-swing-listener-memory-leaks)

Comment: The proper type of reference for 'optional' data such as caching is a SoftReference, not a WeakReference. WeakReference is generally used for preventing reference leaks, explicitly getting higher finalization priority over SoftReferences such that they don't interfere with the storage of cached items during GC sweeps.

Answer (score 4):

To be honest I don't really buy that idea and exactly what you expect to do with a addWeakListener. Maybe it is just me, but it appear to be a wrong good idea. At first it is seducing but the problems it might implies are not negligible.

With weakReference you are not sure that the listener will no longer be called when the listener itself is no longer referenced. The garbage collector can free up menmory a few ms later or never. This mean that it might continue to consume CPU and make strange this like throwing exception because the listener shall not be called.

An example with swing would be to try to do things you can only do if your UI component is actually attached to an active window. This could throw an exception, and affect the notifier making it to crash and preventing valid listeners to be notofied.

Second problem as already stated is anonymous listener, they could be freed too soon never notified at all or only a few times.

What you are trying to achieve is dangerous as you cannot control anymore when you stop receiving notifications. They may last for ever or stop too soon.

Comment: "What you are trying to achieve is dangerous as you cannot control anymore when you stop receiving notifications." - THIS. WeakReferences allow a specially-written listener to be automatically removed, but it's still only when the GC darn well feels like it, which could be *never* and frequently is.

Comment: I wish people would omit the "or stop too soon" part of this argument-- I think that part is a distraction, since that's just a programming error which requires care to avoid but it's not a fundamental problem, and when you mention it it can make people tend to dismiss your whole argument when visually scanning over your answer.  The "may last indefinitely long" part is the real problem, which you rightly point out.

Comment: The stop too soon appear in different cases but is as problematic. If it is just a listener that you'd hope to stay for the life of the application or the same life as the component creating the event to listen to and your listener is garbage collected just after its creation this is a big problem too.

Answer (score 4):

Because you are adding WeakReference listener, I'm assuming, you are using a custom Observable object.

It makes perfect sense to use a WeakReference to an object in the following situation.
- There is a list of listeners in Observable object.
- You already have a hard reference to the listeners somewhere else. (you'd have to be sure of this)
- You don't want the garbage collector to stop clearing the listeners just because there is a reference to it in the Observable.
- During garbage collection the listeners will be cleared up. In the method where you notify the listeners, you clear up the WeakReference objects from the notification list.

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion it's a good idea in most cases. The code that is responsible for releasing the listener is at the same place where it gets registered.

In practice i see a lot of software which is keeping listeners forever. Often programmers are not even aware that they should unregister them.

It usually is possible to return a custom object with a reference to the listener that allows manipulation of when to unregister. For example:

```
listeners.on("change", new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
    System.out.println("hello!");
  }
}).keepFor(someInstance).keepFor(otherInstance);
```

this code would register the listener, return an object that encapsulates the listener and has a method, keepFor that adds the listener to a static weakHashMap with the instance parameter as the key. That would guarantee that the listener is registered at least as long as someInstance and otherInstance are not garbage collected.

There can be other methods like keepForever() or keepUntilCalled(5) or keepUntil(DateTime.now().plusSeconds(5)) or unregisterNow().

Default can be keep forever (until unregistered).

This could also be implemented without weak references but phantom references that trigger the removal of the listener.

edit: created a small lib which implements a basic version of this aproach https://github.com/creichlin/struwwel

Comment: What if garbage collection happens after the call to `on()` but before `keepFor()`? Presumably `keepFor()` calls `weakReference.get()` that may return `null` already at that point?

Comment: @glebm, yes, you are right, that is a problem. very unlikely but that makes it even worse.
Keeping it forever by default, until another method is called would fix that problem. Or just make the reference from the returned object to the listener not weak. So it won't get garbage collected as long as the returned object is in use.

Answer (score 2):

I can't think of any legitimate use case for using WeakReferences for listeners, unless somehow your use case involves listeners that explicitly shouldn't exist after the next GC cycle (that use case, of course, would be VM/platform specific).

It's possible to envision a slightly more legitimate use case for SoftReferences, where the listeners are optional, but take up a lot of heap and should be the first to go when free heap size starts getting dicey. Some sort of optional caching or other type of assisting listener, I suppose, could be a candidate. Even then it seems like you'd want the internals of the listeners to utilize the SoftReferences, not the link between the listener and listenee.

Generally if you're using a persistent listener pattern, though, the listeners are non-optional, so asking this question may be a symptom that you need to reconsider your architecture.

Is this an academic question, or do you have a practical situation you're trying to address? If it's a practical situation I'd love to hear what it is -- and you could probably get more, less abstract advice on how to solve it.

Comment: How about: An object raises an event when something happens.  You would like to have an object with a field or method which reports how many times that has happened.  If no reference to that object exists outside the event which increments that field, the object should cease to exist.  If many objects which monitor a long-lived object are constructed and abandoned, then unless the event is subscribed weakly, the objects will continue to accumulate without bound.

Answer (score 2):

I have 3 suggestions for the original poster.  Sorry for resurrecting an old thread but I think my solutions were not previously discussed in this thread.

First,
Consider following the example of javafx.beans.values.WeakChangeListener in the JavaFX libraries.

Second,
I one upped the JavaFX pattern by modifying the addListener methods of my Observable.  The new addListener() method now creates instances of the corresponding WeakXxxListener classes for me.

The "fire event" method was easily modified to dereference the XxxWeakListeners and to remove them when the WeakReference.get() returned null.

The remove method was now a bit nastier since I need to iterate the entire list, and that means I need to do synchronization.

Third,
Prior to implementing this strategy I employed a different method which you may find useful.  The (hard reference) listeners got a new event they did a reality check of whether or not they were still being used.  If not, then they unsubscribed from the observer which allowed them to be GCed.   For short lived Listeners subscribed to long lived Observables, detecting obsolescence was fairly easy.

In deference to the folks who stipulated that it was "good programming practice to always unsubscribe your listeners, whenever a Listener resorted to unsubscribing itself, I made sure to create a log entry and corrected the problem in my code later.

Comment: This is a 3 year old question, And your "answer" does not seem to be one.

Comment: I did apologize explicitly for resurrecting a 3 year old post.  But when I read this thread it was new to me and I am sure others will stumble across this for the first time too if they Google "weak listener".  I think those people will benefit from my contribution to the discussion as a whole.  In particular, I cited a specific example where weak listeners were used in a modern Java API (which had been brought up).  I also addressed ways of mitigating the "risks" of using weak listeners by suggesting the use of "self removal requires a log entry" policy.

Answer (score 1):

WeakListeners are useful in situations where you specifically want GC to control the lifetime of the listener.

As stated before, this really is different semantics, compared to the usual addListener/removeListener case, but it is valid in some scenarios.

For example, consider a very large tree, which is sparse - some levels of nodes are not explicitly defined, but can be inferred from parent nodes further up the hierarchy. The implicitly defined nodes listen to those parent nodes that are defined so they keep their implied/inherited value up to date. But, the tree is huge - we don't want implied nodes to be around forever - just as long as they are used by the calling code, plus perhaps a LRU cache of a few seconds to avoid churning the same values over and over.

Here, the weak listener makes it possible for child nodes to listen to parents while also having their lifetime decided by reachability/caching so the structure doesn't maintain all the implied nodes in memory.

Answer (score 0):

You may also need to implement your listener with a WeakReference if you are unregistering it somewhere that isn't guaranteed to be called every time.

I seem to recall we had some problems with one of our custom `PropertyChangeSupport` listeners that was used inside row Views in our ListView.  We couldn't find a nice and reliable way to unregister those listeners, so using a WeakReference listener seemed the cleanest solution.

Answer (score 0):

It appears from a test program that anonymous ActionListeners will not prevent an object from being garbage collected:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;

public class ListenerGC {

private static ActionListener al = new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.err.println("blah blah");
        }
    };
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    {
        NoisyButton sec = new NoisyButton("second");
        sec.addActionListener(al);
        new NoisyButton("first");
        //sec.removeActionListener(al);
        sec = null;
    }
    System.out.println("start collect");
    System.gc( );
    System.out.println("end collect");
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    System.out.println("end program");
}

private static class NoisyButton extends JButton {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private final String name;

    public NoisyButton(String name) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    protected void finalize() throws Throwable {
        System.out.println(name + " finalized");
        super.finalize();
    }
}
}
```

produces:

```
start collect
end collect
first finalized
second finalized
end program
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want to do.

If you want to create a reactive value that depends on a specific value but where the callback is not supposed to have side effects, use a weak reference.

If you want to set up a callback which is run for its side effects, use a strong reference.

Imho, this is also why I strongly feel that the observer pattern should be encapsulated into a library most times, with something like Signal/ComputedSignal/Effect and the like.

Your register methods should be named based on what you want to do. The case where you want a reactive dependent value should be something like Subject.dependent_value( (args) => value) while the case with the Effect should be Subject.register_effect((args) => dostuff...).

Effects that depend on dependent values should walk their dependency graphs and register themselves as a strong child of the root observables.

Answer (score 0):

I am a hobbyist programmer but have managed to write some fairly large programs (tens of thousands of lines of Java code).  For decades now, I have avoided weak listeners.  I recently went looking for some memory leaks, my image was growing to multiple gigabytes.  I found every leak to be listener related.  I spent several hours encapsulating all my listeners with weak references just to see what might happen.  It was that or try to write destructors for everything.

All my leaks went away.  I few dozen places I had anonymous classes which caused problems but those were easily found and repaired.

Now, my image remains small and runs faster even after long sessions.  I am now a definite believer in weak references and gladly pay the price of avoiding anonymous class for listeners.

As mentioned elsewhere, I do have a problem flushing all the weak references when the observable doesn’t need to inform the listeners.  When I watch the image size it will occasionally grow fairly large and stay there.  Then, when I move my mouse the weak references get GC’d and the image size collapses.  This doesn’t bother me and I am now a huge believer in weak references.

Again, as a hobbyist, I’m here to strongly recommend weak listeners.